# Inbound rules for security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance, with a security group, let's call it A

In Security Group A, I defined a number of inbound rules

Is there a way to define a second security group, let's call it B, and set some inbound rules in it, and then have security group B, as one of the inbound rules for security group A?

AWS allows me to do that, but it's not working. As in, I added my home IP address, to the inbound rules for security group B, but I can't reach the ec2 instance, unless I add my home IP address to the security group A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add another security group like that, you are saying that the AWS resources that belong to security group B can access the resources in security group A. You aren't combining the rules into a single security group somehow.

Comment: You mean that this tells AWS that the resources in B, can access the resources in A, but NOT the ec2 instance that's using A?

Comment: EC2 instances with security group B assigned to them, can access the EC2 instance with security group A assigned to it. You are adding Security groups as inbound sources. There is no concept of "combining" or "extending" security groups in AWS.